# Execute a query while enter key pressing in java script

Tags: javascript

I want to execute the code behind my Search Button by pressing enter.Any suggestions would be great!

```
    <html:text property="choiceValue" styleId="gestel999" onkeypress="return updateEnter(event,'refreshPage(this)')" style="margin-top:15px;" size="25"/>




function updateEnter(e,refreshPage){
        if(ee.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
            refreshPage()
  }
}
```

Comment: May be you can start implementing your code....

Comment: which button..?? what have you tried so far.? post you code.? where have you tried.?

Comment: Perhaps I'm just tired, but this question made me laugh out loud because the code behind the button could be absolutely anything. Show us your code and tell us clearly and in sufficient detail what you're trying to accomplish or no one can help you.

Comment: The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is your friend.

Comment: You might as well ask a new question. You ruined this one by not providing code soon enough and by tagging completely the wrong programming language.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionListen al = new ActionListener()
{
    // implement ActionListener here
}

button.addActionListener( al );
textField.addActionListener( al );
```

Now the same Action will be invoked when you click on the button or use Enter when focus is on the text field.